# PHP SQL Show one line per code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've written the following code, but I really think it's the wrong way of doing it. Especially if I have more then 5 lines.
What I'm trying to achieve is getting all lines from the table and output them one by one. I tried a while loop but the problem is that every block uses different .css classes.
I think I'm going wrong in the SQL Query, any sugestions would be appreciated.

The code is :

```
$image_one_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$home_table} WHERE home_id=1"); 
$image_one_row = mysql_fetch_array($image_one_sql);
$image_one = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $image_one_row['data'] ) . '"';

$image_two_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$home_table} WHERE home_id=2"); 
$image_two_row = mysql_fetch_array($image_two_sql);
$image_two = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $image_two_row['data'] ) . '"';
```

Comment: `the problem is that every block uses different .css classes`: please show more code so that we can see how to deal with that css issue.

Comment: get the data --> then loop --> then case if or switch

Comment: So to clarify, you want to pull all entries from the "$home_table" and create the 'data/image/jpeg..." string with them?  What are the CSS classes, and how are they determined?  Is it a naming issue, or is it something that is stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $image_one_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$home_table}");
     WHILE ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($image_one_sql)){
    $image[]='data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($rows['data'] )
    }
//pr($image);

then using foreach:

foreach($image as $rows_image){
  //Some code
   }
```